# Repeating webrequest (emulate Charles Proxy)

Tags: c#, proxy

i just want to ask you about a way to make something like what charles proxy do! www.charlesproxy.com it injects or makes proxy between it and browser, so it record each step (Sending and receive or Download and upload), i just wanna to make a project that inject or to be proxy then record the uploaded and received data! :) That's all!

Or just want to know how to start? is it WebRequest as i said?! or how to make it to be proxy via Chrome as example.

If anyone don't know it, just ask what is it?! and i can answer ;).

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0):

Many systems use proxies that are openly available in code across many platforms. For instance, one I've used in the past for proxying GIS queries is the ESRI proxy. The source can be found at https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy and it is quite complete, including forwarding form parameters, iirc. In this case the proxy is used something along the lines of http://proxyurl.com/proxy.ashx?http://www.requestedsite.com. I would start by checking out the source for the .NET subtree of that GIT repo.